# NATS Error while developing echo service

Tags: cloud-foundry, gateway

I'm trying to develop a system service, so I use the echo service as a test.
I developed the service by following the directions on the CF doc.
Now the echo node can be running, but the echo gateway failed with the error "echo_gateway - pid=15040 tid=9321 fid=290e  ERROR -- Exiting due to NATS error: Could not connect to server on nats://localhost:4222/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got into this issue and struck for almost a week finally someone helped me to resolve it. The underlying problemn is something else and since errors are not trapped properly it gives a wrong message. You need to goto github and get the latest code base. The fix for this issue is http://reviews.cloudfoundry.org/#/c/8891 . Once you fix this issue, you will most likely encounter a timeout field issue. the solution for that is to define the timeout field gateway.yml

Comment: Hi KR, can you tell me what should I do to fix the proplem more specifically? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few additional properties became required in the echo_gateway.yml.erb file - specifically, the latest were **default_plan** and **timeout**, under the **service** group.  The properties have been added to the [appropriate file](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-services-sample-release/blob/master/jobs/echo_gateway/templates/echo_gateway.yml.erb#L24) in the vcap-services-sample-release repo.

Looks like the [fix for the misleading error](http://reviews.cloudfoundry.org/#/c/8891/) has been merged into github. I haven't updated and verified this myself just yet but the gerrit comments indicate the solution is the same as what the node base has had for some time. I did previously run into that error handling and it was far more helpful.